# Is there a way to query two SharePoint Choice columns in the same list?

Tags: list, javascript, json

I have a SharePoint list that I'm querying using Javascript and JSON. I have two choice columns called `LifeCycleStatus` and `Priority`.

The results for `LifeCycleStatus` is coming back fine, but for `Priority` it's coming back **[object OBJECT]**.

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and JSON so I think it's something to do with the var query, can you query two choice columns in the same string?

```
 var query = "http://collaboration-dev.norgine.com/sites/it/SystemInventory/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Devices?$expand=LifeCycleStatus&Priority&$filter=Id eq " + window.DeviceId + "";
```

The rest of the code which relates to the Priority column is:

```
   var txtTrafficlight = "";

   var DevicePriority = item.Priority;

    txtTrafficlight = "<p>" + DevicePriority + "</p>";

    $('#devicestatus').append(txtTrafficlight);
```

Comment: You can check by placing debugger in console of browser window. You will find different choice properties for your field which you want to display.

Comment: I don't think the choice properties are the issue. I know what they are, red, amber, green. The question I have is why is the query string returning [object OBJECT] ?

Comment: Check in the debugger to see what the object actually is... Also, can you show how you use LifeCycleStatus?

Comment: Its out of the box behavior for the specific type of field. You need to look more deep in that object to get actual value.

Comment: Cheers, is there an article around on how to do that? I'm still pretty new to this!

Comment: @JanErikGunnar the full code can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44563915/javascript-var-query-returning-object-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Priority" and "LifeCycleStatus" contains an object. You can use the debugger/console to see what the object is - I bet it contains a string with the Value, and the internal ID of the value, possibly other things. Converting an object to a string returns "[object Object]".

"Priority**Value**" and "LifeCycleStatus**Value**" are probably shorthands to the value string.

Comment: Yes, Better use Debugger tools (F12) and see what object contains.

Answer (score 1):

Learn to use the F12 developer console and `console.log()` statements.

You only get [Object Object] when you try to display the value in HTML or use `alert( )`..

Trace to the F12 console and you will see the contents

If you get JSON from a server you can also see the result in the F12 Console **Network** tab (when you reload the page)